# Distance to an affine hyperplane

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $E$ be a finite dimensional, normed space.

Let $H$ be an affine hyperplane of $E$.

Show that there exists $x\in E$ such that $||x||=1$ and $d(x,H) \geq 1$.

I know that for a common (not affine) hyperplane, $\exists x \in E, ||x||=1 \:\text{and} \: d(x,H)= 1$. (you may consider $f$ a linear form with $H$ as kernel and look for $||f||$).

How does that help here to get the point $y$ that fulfills  $||y||=1$ and $d(y,H) \geq 1$ ?

Comment: "Show that there exists $x\in E$ such that $||x||=1$ and $d(y,H)\ge1$". What is $y$?

Comment: @yohBS it's a typo, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Define 
$$ M = \sup_{y\in S} d(y,H) $$
then show that $M \geq 1$ where 
$$ S = \{ y\in E\ |\ \Vert y\Vert = 1\}$$
and to do that on contrary assume that $M < 1$, this implies that 
$diam\ S < 2$ which is not possible.

At last compactness of $S$ gives your desired $x$ when you notice that 
$$ y \mapsto d(y,H) $$
is continious.